# WFS response Format

Tags: wfs, java, wfs-t

I want to develop a WFS Server. When a client request read a layer, What **the response of format** should be?

**Note**: The language of this project is java servlet.

Answer (score 2):

Why are creating your own WFS implementation? Can't you just use [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/)? 
WFS is a complex type of service, this won't be easy.

Anyway the response for WFS-GetFeature should include GML and optionally any other format you want.
[Geotools](http://geotools.org/) can provide you with the right JAVA API's  to do this.

Just look at the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) of geoserver for WFS if you want examples.

Comment: I can use geoserver, but there is no way to work with the users of geoserver with API in my Application.